# Can I install rigid foam board over vapor barrier that is attached to basement wall?

Tags: basement-refinishing, basement-insulation

I recently had my basement waterproofed and a vapor barrier similar to the one in the picture was installed, except our has a dimpled flange at the bottom.  We are also getting ready to finish our basement and I would like to install rigid foam board behind the studs, up against this vapor barrier.  Is there any reason why this would be a bad idea?  I know that normally the foam board is adhered directly to the concrete walls. If I can put up the foam board, should I stop at the flange? Another idea I had was to adhere the foam board directly to the studs and then push them up against the wall before securing it. Finally, would just leaving a gap between the stud wall and concrete wall be best?

[image]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: Where are you located? Does the exterior temperature go from colder on the exterior than interior in winter to warmer on exterior than interior in the summer?